# SQL Server query result to file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, sqsh

How can I save query result into file from sqsh console?

*Google is talking about some gui tools I don't want to use.*

PS: Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with sqsh but if it's a console tool, can you just pipe the output to a file?

```
sqsh <mycommand> >output.txt
```

Comment: `sqsh <options> -m csv -C "select * from ..." >output.csv`

Answer (score 5):

From the [SQSH homepage](http://www.sqsh.org/sqsh_features.html#Pipes):

> You may also redirect output to files and (if you are careful) can
>   redirect input from files:
>
> ```
> 1> select * from sysobjects    
> 2> go 2>/dev/null >/tmp/objects.txt
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with that "sqsh" shell you're talking about.... but on Windows, you could use the command-line `sqlcmd` tool and execute a query against SQL Server, and capture the output into a file.

See:

- [MSDN documentation on sqlcmd (including all possible parameters)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)
- [Tutorial: sqlcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170207.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: @fl00r: stuff like that should be put in your original question from the get go!